# Full height resizing wrong

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a full height sidebar on my bootstrap website, but when I resize the browser, it just goes wrong, as you can see it in the screenshots below.

How can I make it be full height while resizing, and keep everything within the blue side ? Thanks a lot !

[The Codepen : Here](http://codepen.io/zaky/pen/zvqMad)

[image: Full height sidebar in full size]
[image: Full height sidebar in resized]

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="hover-min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">

        <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>       
        <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row animated fadeInLeft">

                <!-- -- -- -- BLUE SIDE -- -- -- -->
                <div class="col-lg-1" id="blueside">

                    <!-- -- -- -- LOGO -- -- -- -->
                    <h1 class="brandlogo animated fadeInLeft">
                        First name <br/>
                        NAME <br/>
                        <span class="orange">
                        JOB <br/>
                        Company<br/>
                        </span> 
                    </h1>

                    <!-- -- -- -- MENU WHY HOW WHO -- -- -- -->
                    <div class="brandlogo text-center animated fadeInLeft" id="menu">
                        <h2><a href="http://www.google.com">WHY</a></h2>
                        <h2><a href="http://www.google.com">HOW</a></h2>
                        <h2><a href="http://www.google.com">WHO</a></h2>
                    </div>


                    <!-- -- -- -- HIRE ME ITEMS-- -- -- -->
                    <div id="hireme" class="text-center">

                        <!-- -- -- -- PORTFOLIO -- -- -- -->
                        <h1 class="brandlogo">Portfolio</h1>

                            <!-- -- -- -- YELLOW DOT -- -- -- -->
                            <div class="puce"><!-- PUCE --></div>

                        <!-- -- -- -- RESUME -- -- -- -->
                        <h1 class="brandlogo hireMeItem">Resume</h1>
                            <div id="viewPDF" class="hvr-underline-from-center"><p>View PDF</p></div>
                            <div class="resumeBox hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>
                            <div class="resumeBox hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>
                            <div class="resumeBox hvr-underline-from-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt resumeBoxIcon"></span></div>

                            <!-- -- -- -- YELLOW DOT -- -- -- -->
                            <div class="puce"><!-- PUCE --></div>

                        <!-- -- -- -- CONTACT -- -- -- -->
                        <h1 class="brandlogo">Contact</h1>
                            <div id="viewPDF" class="hvr-underline-from-center"><p id="contactNumber">+336 31 94 74 90</p></div>
                            <div class="contactBox hvr-underline-from-center"><i id="contactIcon" class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                            <div class="contactBox hvr-underline-from-center"><i id="contactIcon" class="fa fa-skype"></i></span></div>

                    </div> <!-- #hireme -->

                </div> <!-- #blueside -->

            </div> <!-- .container-fluid -->

        </div> <!-- .container -->

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS Code

```
 /* GENERAL SETTINGS*/
html,body{height:100%;}
.container-fluid, .row {
    height:100%;
}
a:hover {
    color : yellow;
    text-decoration : none;
}
a {
    text-decoration : none;
    color : white;
}

/* HOMEPAGE BLUE FILTER EFFECT - not for this page */
img.nyc {
    /*position:fixed;*/
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#opacity {
    position : fixed;
    background-color: #428BCA;
    display:inline-block;
} 
#opacity img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: animation 1s linear;
    -o-animation: animation 1s linear;
    animation: animation 1s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
#landingpage {
    padding : 20px;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#logodiv {
    position : absolute;
    z-index : 0;
}
#rowlandingpage {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.brandlogo{
    color : white;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 2em;
    line-height : 22px;
    margin-top : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
}
.brandlogo h2{
    color : white;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 1em;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-bottom : 0;
}
.yellow {
    color : yellow;
}

#claim{
    color : white;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 4.5em;  
    margin-top : -100px;;
}

#singlebutton {
    background-color : yellow;
    color : #61A4D3;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border-style : none;
    width : 190px;
    height : 50px;
}

#blueside{
    width : 150px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: #64A5D4;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px grey;
}

#menu {
    margin-top : 50px;
}

#hireme {
    margin-top : 80px;
}

.puce{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px/10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px/10px;
    border:solid 8px yellow;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;   
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
}

#viewPDF{
    background-color : red;
    color : #61A4D3;
    font-family : Roboto, sans serif;
    font-weight : 900;
    font-size : 1em;
    width : 110px;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-left : auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-top : 5px;
}

.resumeBox {
    background-color : red;
    width : 34px;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-top : 5px;
}

.resumeBoxIcon {
    color : #64A5D4;
}

#contactNumber {
    font-size : 0.88em;
}

.contactBox {
    background-color : red;
    width : 53px;
    height : 30px;
    line-height : 30px;
    margin-top : 5px;
}

#contactIcon {
    color : #64A5D4;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    line-height : 30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: It might make it easier for users to assist you, if you were to put your code into a demo version in a code snippet or via a jsfiddle.

Comment: jsfiffle that OP didn't do: https://jsfiddle.net/LgcL2vc3/

Comment: Just did :) >>> http://codepen.io/zaky/pen/zvqMad

Comment: Yes it doesn't render as in my browser, this is why I joined screenshots. I updated my question with a codepen though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a fixed positioned aside with 100% height or two columns with equal height; All methods are required `body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }` and `.child { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }`

Solution with fixed position:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.Aside {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #70c1b3;
}
.Main {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f3ffbd;
}
```

```html
<aside class="Aside">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  #Aside
</aside>
<main class="Main">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  #Main
</main>
```

If you need two equal columns with 100% height of body, you can search by "Css equal columns".
Where is one of the realizations with flexbox.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.Aside {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #70c1b3;
  overflow: auto;
}
.Main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f3ffbd;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside class="Aside">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  #Aside
</aside>
<main class="Main">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  #Main
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution who fitted the most my expectations.

Thanks to all others contributors too for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#blueside{
    width : 150px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #64A5D4;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px grey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Items remain in the blue div whatever resizing I do. But in full size, there's a white space under it though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sidebar to always take 100% of the height, and always remain on the side,

```
body {
    height:100%;
    /* Make room for the sidebar */
    margin-left:150px;
}

#blueside {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:150px;
    background-color: #64A5D4;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px grey;
}
```

The fixed positioning insures the sidebar will remain on the side, taking up the same width, and always 100% of the height.

You could also add a wrapper inside the `#blueside` div, like `.sidebar-wrapper`, and add `height:100%;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;` so your sidebar content is scrollable, and always in the right place.

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y:auto;` to `#blueside`. I just tested it on your codepen example and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/owLnxcz5/

use `col-md-3` instead of `col-lg-1`